# Express unknown string object key in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I'm creating a TypScript Declaration file for a client library with a method that returns an object having a variable string key (a record id):

```
getRecords(...): {
  [string]: {  // ??
    first: string,
    last: string,
    ...
  }
};
```

What is the correct way to specify that the key value is only known at runtime, and what is the reference for this?

`getRecords` returns something like:

```
{
  'GuT9b...pX': {
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe',
    ...
  },
  'aMe4T...lk': {
    first: 'Jane',
    last: 'Doe',
    ....
  }
}
```

<sub>(Note that this is a wrapper for an HTTP API written in PHP so I have no control over the result being an associative array (i.e. JavaScript hash), instead of an array with an `.id` field in each element.)</sub>

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Can you show a real example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

```
function getRecords(key: string): { [s: string]: { first: string /*, ...*/ } } {
    return { [key]: { first: 'John' } }
}
```